# Execution of created .txt files on the desktop

Tags: pi-3b+

How can I execute text files by clicking on them on the desktop?

By this I mean me following the following process:

1. Creating a .txt file on a Raspberry Pi desktop
2. Typing out executable code inside of that desktop .txt file and saving it onto the desktop.
3. Clicking on the .txt file which is on the desktop and have it automatically open up the terminal, place the executable code inside of the terminal and then running that executable code from the .txt file that I clicked on which was saved onto the Desktop from step 2.

Comment: You mean .sh files?

Comment: Yep and right when you said that I face facepalmed myself.

Comment: This post almost made me snort my coffee. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on that file and select "Properties". Check the tabs for an checkbox called "Executable". Select it.

**Make sure that the first line of your file has a proper "shebang".** If your .txt file is a bash script, the first line must be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

If it is a Python script, the first line must be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a suggestion by a lovely commentor by the name of user90248 I realized that you can create a .sh file and then run it using the following commands.

sudo nano "name-of-file".sh

then create an executable file in the same folder

sudo chmod +x "name-of-file".sh

then find the file and run it

[image]

Comment: A better in-depth analysis into the process can be seen using this link: http://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-write-and-run-a-shell-script-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: There's no need to use `sudo` unless you are writing the file somewhere not accessible by the current user.